# How to set p-label on netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I was working on a code on Netlogo that makes a maze that you can interact with and I wanted to label one of the patches start.  How would you include that in the code? I only know how to do it temporarily on the interface screen. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
to setup 
  ask patch 0 0 [set plabel "start"]
end
```

[image]